# Get the value of a Label from a general item

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, typeof

I have a grid with labels and text boxes.
I want to get the content of the label.
Very easy if you know it is a label.
But this is what I have:

```
foreach (var t in Grid1.Children)
    {
         if (t.GetType() == typeof(Label))
         {
                string val = t.????;
         }
    }
```

How do I get the content of this label?

Comment: how about t.Content.ToString(); ?

Comment: Not there... It only has tostring, gettype, gethashcode and equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach (var t in Grid1.Children)
    {
         if (t is Label)
         {
                string val = ((Label)t).Content.ToString()
         }
    }
```